# Complex Python List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Can somebody explain how exactly is list comprehension working here?

```
page = 'one two one three\n' * 10
unique_words = list(word  for line in page for word in line.split())
print unique_words
```

OUTPUT

```
['o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'w', 'o', 'o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'w', 'o', 'o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'w', 'o', 'o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e']
```

I am confused over where the variables are declared and where they are used?
e.g. Initially we only know about page as a string,

`line in page` -> should return each character from the string.

`word in line.split()` -> is removing '\n' and whitespaces and returning each character

and hence the output. But I still don't understand the way of writing it so that the compiler understands what I want.

**QUESTION**: How exactly is `word  for line in page for word in line.split()` processed by the compiler **step by step**?

Comment: `for line in page` doesn't do what you think (hint: `print line`).

Comment: It sounds like you know what Python is doing with your code. Why are you asking about compiler details? Those aren't going to help you. It looks like the information you actually need is how to go over your string line by line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to see the double `for` loops as nested, from left to right:

```
for line in page:
    for word in line.split():
        word
```

You have *one long string* going in, so `for line in page` loops over each *individual character*; `line` is one character at a time. Splitting that character gives you a list with just that one character, unless that character is whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.):

```
>>> page = 'one two one three\n' * 10
>>> list(page)
['o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\n', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\n', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\n', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\n', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\n', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\n', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\n', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\n', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\n', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\n']
>>> page[0].split()
['o']
>>> page[3].split()
[]
```

so the end result is a list with individual characters.

Note that technically speaking you have a *generator expression* feeding a `list()` call; the output is the same a list comprehension however. You'd get a list comprehension if you replaced `list(...)` with `[...]`.

If you wanted *unique words*, use a `set()` instead and just a simple `str.split()` call, no need for looping:

```
unique_words = set(page.split())
```

`str.split()` will already split your sentences into words on *all whitespace*, including the newlines; `set()` removes any duplicates:

```
>>> set(page.split())
{'two', 'one', 'three'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martijn. This is exactly what I was looking for(the arrangement you showed as nested for loops). Actually it was initially as a set only. I changed it to list to make sense of the complete output.
Again, Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

You read that left to right:

```
[word  for line in page for word in line.split()]
```

is the same as:

```
mylist=[]
for line in page:
    for word in line.split():
        mylist.append(word)
```

Comment: Thanks @mbatchkarov for your time. I got it now.